# How to observe Glide loading state?

Tags: android, android-glide

I have two imageViews, and one use Glide to get a URL_image_Resource.

The other one is my problem.
I wanna change its imageResource according to glide communication between the internet.
But I don't know the way to do it...
Is it possible to observe Glide work? Thanks in advance.

e.g.) such as..

```
when (glide.state) {  
  is Loading_now -> R.drawable.loading  
  is Achieve_fetching_Image -> R.drawable.achieve_fetching_URLImage  
  is Loading_error -> R.drawable.error  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Glide support some ways to do that:

1. PlaceHolder + Error drawable

   ```
        Glide.with(this)
           .load("https://picsum.photos/3000/3000")
           .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_loader)
           .error(R.drawable.ic_error)
           .fitCenter()
           .into(ivContent)
   ```
2. RequestListener

   ```
   Glide.with(this)
       .load("https://picsum.photos/3000/3000")
       .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
           override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
               //TODO onLoadFailed
               return false
           }

           override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean ): Boolean {
               //TODO onResourceReady
               return false
           }

       })
       .fitCenter()
       .into(ivContent)
   ```